# How do you schedule a fade-out using setTargetAtTime

Tags: scheduled-tasks, web-audio-api, pitch

I am having problems with the 'windowing', as it's called, of pitch-shifted grains of sounds using the Web Audio API. When I play the sound, I successfully set the initial gain to 0, using setValueAtTime, and successfully fade the sound in using linearRampToValueAtTime. However, I am not successful in scheduling a fade-out to occur slightly before the sound ends. It may be because the sound is pitch-shifted, although in the code below, I believe I have set the parameters correctly. Though maybe the final parameter in setTargetAtTime is not suitable because I don't fully understand that parameter, despite having read Chris's remarks on the matter. How does one successfully schedule a fade-out when the sound is pitch-shifted, using setTargetAtTime? Below is my code. You can see the piece itself at https://vispo.com/animisms/enigman2/2022

```
            source.buffer = audioBuffer;
            source.connect(this.GrainObjectGain);
            this.GrainObjectGain.connect(app.mainGain);
            source.addEventListener('ended', this.soundEnded);
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Now we do the 'windowing', ie, when we play it, we fade it in,
            // and we set it to fade out at the end of play. The fade duration
            // in seconds is a maximum of 10 milliseconds and 
            // a minimum of 10% of the duration of the sound. This helps 
            // eliminate pops.
            source.playbackRate.value = this.playbackRate;
            var fadeDurationInSeconds = Math.min(0.01,0.1*duration*this.playbackRate);
            this.GrainObjectGain.gain.setValueAtTime(0, app.audioContext.currentTime);
            this.GrainObjectGain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(app.constantGrainGain, app.audioContext.currentTime+fadeDurationInSeconds);
            this.GrainObjectGain.gain.setTargetAtTime(0, app.audioContext.currentTime+duration*this.playbackRate-fadeDurationInSeconds, fadeDurationInSeconds);
            source.start(when, offset, duration);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your comment below I guess you want to schedule the fade out `fadeDurationInSeconds` before the sound ends.

Since you change `playbackRate` you need to divide the original `duration` by that `playbackRate` to get the actual duration.

Changing your `setTargetAtTime()` call as follows should schedule the fade out at the desired point in time.

```
this.GrainObjectGain.gain.setTargetAtTime(
    0,
    app.audioContext.currentTime + duration / this.playbackRate - fadeDurationInSeconds,
    fadeDurationInSeconds
);
```

Please not that `setTargetAtTime()` actually never reaches the `target`. At least in theory. It comes reasonably close though after some time. But that time is longer as the `timeConstant`.

The relevant text from the spec can be found here: https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-audioparam-settargetattime

> Start exponentially approaching the target value at the given time with a rate having the given time constant. Among other uses, this is useful for implementing the "decay" and "release" portions of an ADSR envelope. **Please note that the parameter value does not immediately change to the target value at the given time, but instead gradually changes to the target value.**

The `timeConstant` parameter roughly defines the time it takes to reach 2/3 of the desired signal attenuation.

It's mentioned here: https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-audioparam-settargetattime-timeconstant

> More precisely, timeConstant is the time it takes a first-order linear continuous time-invariant system to reach the value 1−1/ (around 63.2%) given a step input response (transition from 0 to 1 value).

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I updated the answer.

Comment: Fantastic, Chris! Thanks so much! Calloo callay! I multiplied whereas I should have divided by playbackRate. I corrected my error--and the piece sounds better. Almost no little pops. I'm thrilled. I'm not seeing any problems, which suggests I don't need to worry about canceling scheduled fade-outs in the event that the sound is stopped before the scheduled fade-out occurs? Is that handled by the system?

Comment: Yes, I think that's fine. The `GainNode` should not care if the `AudioBufferSourceNode` plays anything or not.

Comment: What if playback rate changes dynamically during playback, how then it should be done?

Comment: That's tricky, there are two things ([1](https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/2397), [2](https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/2410)) discussed right now which would make it easier to know what's going on on the audio thread but they are not implemented anywhere yet.